# Class Design - property of several possible types

Tags: c#, json

Take a class `Player`, which (currently) has a property of type `Role`:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; protected set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Where `Role` holds a few distinct values:

```
public class Role
{
    public double DamageModifier { get { return _damageModifier; } }
    public double DefenseModifier { get { return _defenseModifier; } }
    public double HealthModifier { get { return _healthModifier; } }

    private double _damageModifier;
    private double _defenseModifier;
    private double _healthModifier;

    public Role(double damageMod, double defenseMod, double healthMod)
    {
        _damageModifier = damageMod;
        _defenseModifier = defenseMod;
        _healthModifier = healthMod;
    }
}
```

And there are a few "classes" that derive from Role:

```
public class Archer : Role
{
    private const double _damageModifier = 1.2;
    private const double _defenseModifier = 0.9;
    private const double _healthModifier = 0.8;

    public Archer() : base(_damageModifier, _defenseModifier, _healthModifier) { }
}

public class Mage : Role
{
    private const double _damageModifier = 1.4;
    private const double _defenseModifier = 0.7;
    private const double _healthModifier = 0.9;

    public Mage() : base(_damageModifier, _defenseModifier, _healthModifier) { }
}

public class Warrior : Role
{
    private const double _damageModifier = 1.0;
    private const double _defenseModifier = 1.2;
    private const double _healthModifier = 1.0;

    public Warrior() : base(_damageModifier, _defenseModifier, _healthModifier) { }
}
```

The end result of all this is really just that the `Player.Role` property is a placeholder for what will become an `Archer`, `Mage`, or `Warrior`. However, this specific subtype is decided at run-time (or more specifically, at character creation).

The issue I'm having arose from trying to `serialize` the player object to `JSON` data. When `JSON` serializes the `Role` property, it knows that it's a `Role` object and is able to get the corresponding `xxModifier` values from the instance, but I lose the fact that the `Role` property was a class derived from `Role`.

I'm obviously still learning, but this sort of issue kind of tells me that I've messed up in designing this class and it needs to be fixed. I could refactor the constructor so that `Role` holds a reference to the child class, but that seems wrong too.

**EDIT** Based on comments:
My intention for the `Archer/Mage/Warrior` classes is that each class will have certain methods (abilities) available to it, in addition to the `xxModifier` properties that currently exist, such that a `Warrior` will do (comparatively) less damage but have higher defense and health, and the `Role` class currently serves as a way to give the `Player` object a place to hold his Role (RPG class). This specific implementation is my goal, and what's listed here is what I've come up with so far.

- Is the `Role` class even necessary in this case?
- Assuming a redesign of these classes is warranted, how can I best write this so that a `Player` object ***is a*** `Archer/Mage/Warrior`?

Comment: I've encountered this before, and have used json.net to create type-aware json representations of my object graphs.  It essentially creates pseudo properties on the objects recording the original type.  Worked well.

Comment: As @Will suggested, there are ways to do this which basically involve adding a property that can identify the class. See [TypeNameHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) for example.

Comment: You do not need a new class to differentiate on values. Just use one role class. You use subclassing to add behavior, not data. Because if you continue with this design, you'll end up with a `SwordWieldingMageWhoCanRunVeryFast` and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster: True, but lets assume that a) the difference in values aren't the only difference, or at least if they are now, they might not be in the future and b) having different classes makes it easier to test if a player is a certain class, i.e. `if (Player.Role.GetType() == typeof(Mage))`

Comment: @CodeCaster I would prefer to keep the separate classes. At this point, they only contain references to `damage/defense/health` modifiers, but they will eventually contain other things like abilities. Additionally, I want to be able to refer to the player as one of these subtypes (`Warrior` etc).

Comment: Yeah, see edit to my comment, was responding to other questions in the meantime. Use composition, not inheritance. Again, different classes are for different behavior. You also don't create a class per table row in your ORM, you use one entity class and fill instances of it with different data. For actual different behavior you can use different classes.

Comment: @Matt code that makes decisions based on the type of objects like that always is a design smell. Also, you do not design for what you might need in the future.

Comment: @CodeCaster on your update - that's the kind of thing I'm trying to avoid here. My "vision" of the implementation is that each (RPG) class has a base modifier - (ex: warriors do less damage but have higher hp/def), and have certain methods (abilities) available to them that aren't available to the other classes. I don't quite understand the idea of composition vs. inheritance; if you'd like to provide an example (basic is perfectly fine) of designing it this way, this is precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the immediate question of how to serialize and deserialize to JSON while retaining type, using something like JSON.Net, this is pretty trivial to do:

```
var p = new Player() { Role = new Mage() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });
```

Now you JSON will look something like this:

```
{
    "$type": "MyApp.Program+Player, MyApp",
    "Name": null,
    "
Health": 0,
    "Role": {
        "$type": "MyApp.Program+Mage, MyApp",
        "DamageModifier": 1.4,
        "DefenseModifier": 0.7,
        "HealthModifier": 0.9
    }
}
```

The additional `$type` properties are added so when you deserialize:

```
var d = (Player)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Player), new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects });
var isMage = d.Role.GetType() == typeof(Mage);  // true
```

The question of whether or not your design is a good idea or not (as discussed in the comments) is a little broader.

Comment: I was meaning to ask about this :) thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had a chance to test this, and it works beautifully!

Comment: very much belated (sorry), but I have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different problems here: specification and implementation.

In the specification, so in your game back-end, or hardcoded, or in your database or whatever, you want to be able to specify the attributes for various character classes for your player. This is fine.

That each specification holds different values does however not warrant a different implementation. You use subclassing to add **behavior**. You're not adding behavior, just altering existing behavior (I guess your non-shown damage calculation) slightly, based on the values of the player's role.

Furthermore, I now suspect you have in code something like this:

```
void NewPlayerButtonClicked(string characterClass)
{
    var player = new Player();

    if (characterClass == "Mage")
    {
        player.Role = new Mage();
    }

    // ...
}
```

That in and of itself is a design smell.

You just need a Role class to hold the values:

```
public class Role
{
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public decimal DamageModifier { get; set; }
    public decimal DefenseModifier { get; set; }
    public decimal HealthModifier { get; set; }
}
```

And in your player handling code you access the role's properties:

```
public decimal GetAttackDamage(Player attacker, Player defender, AttackInfo attack)
{
    // do calculations with attacker.Role.N and defender.Role.N
}
```

Now I guess you're asking this because you want to populate the fields while creating a character, or loading a game state. You can do that for example by storing your specification in JSON:

```
{
    "characterClasses" :    
    [
        {
            "className" : "Mage",
            "damageModifier" : 1.4,
            "defenseModifier" : 0.7,
            "healthModifier" : 0.9,
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Then if you save the player's character class, loading the data becomes very trivial:

```
player.Role = rolesLoadedFromJson.First(r => r.ClassName == player.CharacterClass);
```

But on all of this many books have been written, and the question is far too abstract (and the subject too broad) to give an in-depth answer on all aspects of object-oriented design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So doing it this way, the `Role` subclasses are basically moved from the code to JSON data and my (now single) `Role` class is loaded from this data?

Comment: Also - with (later) adding abilities and such, how would these be differentiated in JSON? At this point, I expect they would be methods specific to the subclasses I currently have unless there's another way I'm not aware of.

Comment: Yes, the subclasses from your example are actually just different data, which belong in different instances of the same class. As for the "abilities", that depends entirely on what an ability does. Create subclasses per _category_ of ability, and give them one method, like `Apply()`, where the subclass does its logic (like damage over time, disable some ability of a player, and so on). But again, this subject is quite abstract and broad.

Comment: Understood on it being broad, apologies for that. Thanks for indulging me! You've given me some things to think about and research.

Comment: No problem, your question as such is very answerable, but each of the question that logically follows deserves an own topic.